# Spring Boot, JS. Не работает показ пароля в input. Но начинает работать если пользователь авторизовался

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

```js
function show_hide_password(target){
    var input = document.getElementById('password-input');
    if (input.getAttribute('type') === 'password') {
        target.classList.add('view');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    } else {
        target.classList.remove('view');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'password');
    }
    return false;
}
```

```css
.input {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    position: relative;
}
#password-input, #username-input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-indent: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.password-control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    right: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(https://snipp.ru/demo/495/view.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.password-control.view {
    background: url(https://snipp.ru/demo/495/no-view.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<section  class="authorization">
    <form th:action="@{/}" th:authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler" method="post">
        <div>
            <div class="input">
                <input type="text" id="username-input" name="username" placeholder="Логин">
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <input type="password" id="password-input" placeholder="Пароль" name="password">
                <a href="#" class="password-control" onclick="return show_hide_password(this);"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <input type="submit" id="asubmit" class="buttonAuth" value="Авторизоваться" >
            </div>
    </form>

</section>
```

При старте приложения не работает показ пароля в input. Но начинает работать после авторизации. Я авторизовался, вернулся обратно на страницу и "Глазик" работает, мне показывает и скрывает пароль.
Опять же если разлогинюсь, показ пароля снова перестает работать, почему? Что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: А что в консоле пишет при клике на глаз когда не работает показ пароля ?

Comment: Не смотрел, но уже решил проблему :)

Answer (score 0):

Данную проблему решил следующим образом - добавил имя директории "/js/**"

```
/* Разрешаем Spring Security допускать следующие директории */
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**","/js/**");
    }
```

И при старте приложения "глазик" работает :)